# Any way to to defer Asterisk sip accounts/peers to node.js?

Tags: node.js, sip, asterisk

I was wondering if it would be possible to defer the sip accounts normally listed in Asterisk's sip.conf to a sort-of 'AGI' in node.js much the same way you can do for call routing in extensions.conf. The idea is to make use of a Redis data-store and allow some scripting in javascript whenever someone registers or disconnects -- instead of using something like autocreatepeer or a file generated from a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

You have 2 options.

1) setup odbc interface to Redis and use asterisk realtime

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime

2) create fastagi interface using  node.js(http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+FastAGI) or do include external script as part of config file

```
---------extensions.conf-------
# here is script which send to STDOUT extensions.conf file
#exec "somescript.sh"
```

Correct way is first.

Actualy for you task effective way is create some fastagi script which will do curl request to your node-js and ask data(for extensions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but how would one do a fasstagi script with list of peers as opposed to extensions? Is there a page somewhere that explains the syntax?

Comment: No, fastagi can do only extensions. List of peers can be returned by #exec(require reload) or directly from db(not require reload). As i understand you want get all working without learn somethign new, i think for you better hire freelancer. Sure you can use node.js to control asterisk,but looks like resulting system will be realy bad one and never work with more then 1-5 users.

Comment: I was simply asking a question... that you didn't read, I guess. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I have read your question compleatly. Unfortanly no way do api call on registration in asterisk.If you want do that, you can use kamilio/opensips. But that way of operation is higly not recomended and request for it mean you not understand architecture. You have read at least simple book like "Asterisk the future of telephony" to understand what is wrong with your question.

Comment: IF you still think you want asterisk control on peers from node.js, you always can create "node.js odbc driver". But again, that is wrong way. Correct way create interface to redis directly.

Comment: The reason I ask questions is to understand the architecture, and its limitations. Apparently, it has a hefty load of crippling limitations. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I think you have read book for beginers to get image of architecture.